# How to get access to the WEB-INF/views/some.jsp? spring mvc

Tags: java, tomcat, mvc

I successfully deployed my webapp to the Tomcat localhost. My app has 2 pages: localhost:8080/spring-mvc and localhost:8080/home. The first page has a link to the second. When I start my app, it successfully opens the first page, but when I follow the link to the second page the error appears:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.

It seems like there is no access to the WEB-INF/view folder. Can you help me to resolve this problem?

[image: Project structure]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.stoliarenko"/>

        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
              <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
          </bean>
</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Index Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="/home">Go To Home Page!!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>${pageTitle}</title>
</head>
<body>
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.stoliarenko;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public ModelAndView home(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
        modelAndView.addObject("pageTitle", "Home Page");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Hi, Welcome! This is HomePage!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Root Cause
The class require to resolve the JSP path is available in tomcat jasper package and the dependency is not added in pom.xml. Hence, spring boot application is not able to resolve the jsp path.

Solution
The dependent classes are available in tomcat jasper.

this link may be useful
http://www.codersdesks.com/spring-boot-path-with-web-inf-or-meta-inf/